# PDF editing gem for ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, rubygems

I have a rails app in which user submits a PDF file. I want to edit that PDF file such that i can have line numbers on each line in it. Is there any gem that can help me in doing this task?

If there is not any gem for PDF then is there any way or any gem that i can use to edit word file to add line numbers in the doc file?

Comment: Editing text in a PDF is not as easy as in your typical Office suite as PDF was not designed for this capability. There are some ways to create a PDF to make it easier later on to extract semantic information but if this information is not there, you can only apply heuristics to get text and its meaning (i.e. is this a paragraph or a heading?). So you are better off using another source format like ODT or DOCX.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two ways you can go.

- The first way - parse and recreate new PDF files with [wicked_pdf](https://rubygems.org/gems/wicked_pdf)
  gem
- The second way - edit existing PDF files with [pdf-forms](https://rubygems.org/gems/pdf-forms) gem